# memory leak problems

Tags: .net, c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks

I used `_CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC` and put `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` at the program exit to detect memory leak, and got the following memory leak report:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(188) : {178432} normal block at 0x00FE6BC8, 2150 bytes long.
 Data: < x * > E4 B8 B3 78 CD 02 00 00 2A 04 00 00 01 00 00 00 
{178227} normal block at 0x00FE6050, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < ` ` v > 08 60 FE 00 08 60 FE 00 E0 76 A7 01 
{178226} normal block at 0x00FE6008, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <P` P` > 50 60 FE 00 50 60 FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{178225} normal block at 0x00FE5FC0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <p_ > 70 5F FE 00 98 F4 13 00 
{178224} normal block at 0x00FE5F68, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < $ 8^ _ ` > 00 24 FE 00 38 5E FE 00 C0 5F FE 00 08 60 FE 00 
{178223} normal block at 0x00FE5F20, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < ^ ^ > D8 5E FE 00 D8 5E FE 00 C0 82 A7 01 
{178222} normal block at 0x00FE5ED8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < _ _ > 20 5F FE 00 20 5F FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{178221} normal block at 0x00FE5E90, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <@^ > 40 5E FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{178220} normal block at 0x00FE5E38, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <h_ ] ^ ^ > 68 5F FE 00 08 5D FE 00 90 5E FE 00 D8 5E FE 00 
{176947} normal block at 0x00FE5DF0, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < ] ] x > A8 5D FE 00 A8 5D FE 00 78 82 A7 01 
{176946} normal block at 0x00FE5DA8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < ] ] > F0 5D FE 00 F0 5D FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{176945} normal block at 0x00FE5D60, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < ] > 10 5D FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{176944} normal block at 0x00FE5D08, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <8^ [ `] ] > 38 5E FE 00 D8 5B FE 00 60 5D FE 00 A8 5D FE 00 
{174511} normal block at 0x00FE5CC0, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <x\ x\ @ > 78 5C FE 00 78 5C FE 00 40 98 A7 01 
{174510} normal block at 0x00FE5C78, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < \ \ > C0 5C FE 00 C0 5C FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{174509} normal block at 0x00FE5C30, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < [ > E0 5B FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{174508} normal block at 0x00FE5BD8, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < ] Z 0\ x\ > 08 5D FE 00 A8 5A FE 00 30 5C FE 00 78 5C FE 00 
{171891} normal block at 0x00FE5B90, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <H[ H[ @n > 48 5B FE 00 48 5B FE 00 40 6E A7 01 
{171890} normal block at 0x00FE5B48, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < [ [ > 90 5B FE 00 90 5B FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{171889} normal block at 0x00FE5B00, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < Z > B0 5A FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{171888} normal block at 0x00FE5AA8, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < [ xY [ H[ > D8 5B FE 00 78 59 FE 00 00 5B FE 00 48 5B FE 00 
{166775} normal block at 0x00FE5A60, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < Z Z > 18 5A FE 00 18 5A FE 00 D0 A3 A7 01 
{166774} normal block at 0x00FE5A18, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <`Z `Z > 60 5A FE 00 60 5A FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{166773} normal block at 0x00FE59D0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < Y > 80 59 FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{166772} normal block at 0x00FE5978, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < Z HX Y Z > A8 5A FE 00 48 58 FE 00 D0 59 FE 00 18 5A FE 00 
{161217} normal block at 0x00FE5930, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < X X h > E8 58 FE 00 E8 58 FE 00 68 86 A7 01 
{161216} normal block at 0x00FE58E8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <0Y 0Y > 30 59 FE 00 30 59 FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{161215} normal block at 0x00FE58A0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <PX > 50 58 FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{161214} normal block at 0x00FE5848, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <xY W X X > 78 59 FE 00 18 57 FE 00 A0 58 FE 00 E8 58 FE 00 
{153281} normal block at 0x00FE5800, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < W W > B8 57 FE 00 B8 57 FE 00 00 A5 A7 01 
{153280} normal block at 0x00FE57B8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < X X > 00 58 FE 00 00 58 FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{153279} normal block at 0x00FE5770, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < W > 20 57 FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{153278} normal block at 0x00FE5718, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <HX U pW W > 48 58 FE 00 E8 55 FE 00 70 57 FE 00 B8 57 FE 00 
{145248} normal block at 0x00FE56D0, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < V V @o > 88 56 FE 00 88 56 FE 00 40 6F A9 01 
{145247} normal block at 0x00FE5688, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < V V > D0 56 FE 00 D0 56 FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{145246} normal block at 0x00FE5640, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < U > F0 55 FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{145245} normal block at 0x00FE55E8, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < W T @V V > 18 57 FE 00 B8 54 FE 00 40 56 FE 00 88 56 FE 00 
{138595} normal block at 0x00FE55A0, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <XU XU > 58 55 FE 00 58 55 FE 00 C0 BA A7 01 
{138594} normal block at 0x00FE5558, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < U U > A0 55 FE 00 A0 55 FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{138593} normal block at 0x00FE5510, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < T > C0 54 FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{138592} normal block at 0x00FE54B8, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < U S U XU > E8 55 FE 00 88 53 FE 00 10 55 FE 00 58 55 FE 00 
{126958} normal block at 0x00FE5470, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <(T (T x > 28 54 FE 00 28 54 FE 00 78 90 A7 01 
{126957} normal block at 0x00FE5428, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <pT pT > 70 54 FE 00 70 54 FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{126956} normal block at 0x00FE53E0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < S > 90 53 FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{126955} normal block at 0x00FE5388, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < T XR S (T > B8 54 FE 00 58 52 FE 00 E0 53 FE 00 28 54 FE 00 
{115884} normal block at 0x00FE5340, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < R R > F8 52 FE 00 F8 52 FE 00 00 9D A7 01 
{115883} normal block at 0x00FE52F8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <@S @S > 40 53 FE 00 40 53 FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{115882} normal block at 0x00FE52B0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <`R > 60 52 FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{115881} normal block at 0x00FE5258, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < S (Q R R > 88 53 FE 00 28 51 FE 00 B0 52 FE 00 F8 52 FE 00 
{103197} normal block at 0x00FE5210, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < Q Q ` > C8 51 FE 00 C8 51 FE 00 60 AD A7 01 
{103196} normal block at 0x00FE51C8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < R R > 10 52 FE 00 10 52 FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{103195} normal block at 0x00FE5180, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <0Q > 30 51 FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{103194} normal block at 0x00FE5128, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <XR O Q Q > 58 52 FE 00 F8 4F FE 00 80 51 FE 00 C8 51 FE 00 
{90079} normal block at 0x00FE50E0, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < P P > 98 50 FE 00 98 50 FE 00 90 A8 A7 01 
{90078} normal block at 0x00FE5098, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < P P > E0 50 FE 00 E0 50 FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{90077} normal block at 0x00FE5050, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < P > 00 50 FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{90076} normal block at 0x00FE4FF8, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <(Q a PP P > 28 51 FE 00 C8 61 FE 00 50 50 FE 00 98 50 FE 00 
{79611} normal block at 0x00FE6268, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < b b G > 20 62 FE 00 20 62 FE 00 A8 47 A7 01 
{79610} normal block at 0x00FE6220, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <hb hb > 68 62 FE 00 68 62 FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{79609} normal block at 0x00FE48E8, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < a > D0 61 FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{79608} normal block at 0x00FE61C8, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < O $ H b > F8 4F FE 00 00 24 FE 00 E8 48 FE 00 20 62 FE 00 
{62335} normal block at 0x00FE2400, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < a h_  > C8 61 FE 00 68 5F FE 00 CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
{62334} normal block at 0x00FE2F68, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < > 84 F4 13 00 A4 F4 13 00 
{62142} normal block at 0x00FE4138, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < ' @ v > F8 27 FE 00 F0 40 FE 00 E0 76 A7 01 
{62141} normal block at 0x00FE40F0, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <8A @ > 38 41 FE 00 A8 40 FE 00 C0 82 A7 01 
{62140} normal block at 0x00FE40A8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < @ ( x > F0 40 FE 00 88 28 FE 00 78 82 A7 01 
{62139} normal block at 0x00FE2888, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < @ @( @ > A8 40 FE 00 40 28 FE 00 40 98 A7 01 
{62138} normal block at 0x00FE2840, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < ( ' @n > 88 28 FE 00 F8 27 FE 00 40 6E A7 01 
{62137} normal block at 0x00FE27F8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <@( 8A > 40 28 FE 00 38 41 FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{62136} normal block at 0x00FE27B0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < " > B0 22 FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{62135} normal block at 0x00FE22A8, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < X' ' ' > 08 F9 03 00 58 27 FE 00 B0 27 FE 00 F8 27 FE 00 
{61208} normal block at 0x00FE4060, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <X& @ > 58 26 FE 00 18 40 FE 00 D0 A3 A7 01 
{61207} normal block at 0x00FE4018, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <`@ ? h > 60 40 FE 00 D0 3F FE 00 68 86 A7 01 
{61206} normal block at 0x00FE3FD0, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < @ ? > 18 40 FE 00 88 3F FE 00 00 A5 A7 01 
{61205} normal block at 0x00FE3F88, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < ? & @o > D0 3F FE 00 A0 26 FE 00 40 6F A9 01 
{61204} normal block at 0x00FE26A0, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < ? X& > 88 3F FE 00 58 26 FE 00 C0 BA A7 01 
{61203} normal block at 0x00FE2658, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < & `@ > A0 26 FE 00 60 40 FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{61202} normal block at 0x00FE2610, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <`' > 60 27 FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{61201} normal block at 0x00FE2758, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < " > & X& > A8 22 FE 00 E8 3E FE 00 10 26 FE 00 58 26 FE 00 
{58938} normal block at 0x00FE43E0, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <xB C x > 78 42 FE 00 98 43 FE 00 78 90 A7 01 
{58937} normal block at 0x00FE4398, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < C PC > E0 43 FE 00 50 43 FE 00 00 9D A7 01 
{58936} normal block at 0x00FE4350, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < C C ` > 98 43 FE 00 08 43 FE 00 60 AD A7 01 
{58935} normal block at 0x00FE4308, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <PC B > 50 43 FE 00 C0 42 FE 00 90 A8 A7 01 
{58934} normal block at 0x00FE42C0, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < C xB G > 08 43 FE 00 78 42 FE 00 A8 47 A7 01 
{58933} normal block at 0x00FE4278, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < B C > C0 42 FE 00 E0 43 FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{58932} normal block at 0x00FE3F40, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < > > F0 3E FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{58931} normal block at 0x00FE3EE8, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <X' @? xB > 58 27 FE 00 08 F9 03 00 40 3F FE 00 78 42 FE 00 
{54356} normal block at 0x00FE3EA0, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < > X> pw > 10 3E FE 00 58 3E FE 00 70 77 A7 01 
{54355} normal block at 0x00FE3E58, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < > > (w > A0 3E FE 00 10 3E FE 00 28 77 A7 01 
{54354} normal block at 0x00FE3E10, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <X> > > 58 3E FE 00 A0 3E FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{54353} normal block at 0x00FE25C8, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < / > B8 2F FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{54352} normal block at 0x00FE2FB0, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <h . % > > 68 F8 03 00 90 2E FE 00 C8 25 FE 00 10 3E FE 00 
{54341} normal block at 0x00FE3DC8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < < = v > F0 3C FE 00 80 3D FE 00 E0 76 A7 01 
{54340} normal block at 0x00FE3D80, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < = 8= > C8 3D FE 00 38 3D FE 00 C0 82 A7 01 
{54339} normal block at 0x00FE3D38, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < = < x > 80 3D FE 00 F0 3C FE 00 78 82 A7 01 
{54338} normal block at 0x00FE3CF0, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <8= = > 38 3D FE 00 C8 3D FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{54337} normal block at 0x00FE2538, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < . > 98 2E FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{54336} normal block at 0x00FE2E90, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < / ! 8% < > B0 2F FE 00 D0 21 FE 00 38 25 FE 00 F0 3C FE 00 
{54279} normal block at 0x00FE3CA8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < ; `< > D0 3B FE 00 60 3C FE 00 D0 A3 A7 01 
{54278} normal block at 0x00FE3C60, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < < < h > A8 3C FE 00 18 3C FE 00 68 86 A7 01 
{54277} normal block at 0x00FE3C18, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <`< ; > 60 3C FE 00 D0 3B FE 00 00 A5 A7 01 
{54276} normal block at 0x00FE3BD0, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < < < > 18 3C FE 00 A8 3C FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{54275} normal block at 0x00FE2F20, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < ! > D8 21 FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{54274} normal block at 0x00FE21D0, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < . X: / ; > 90 2E FE 00 58 3A FE 00 20 2F FE 00 D0 3B FE 00 
{54166} normal block at 0x00FE3B88, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < : @; x > B0 3A FE 00 40 3B FE 00 78 90 A7 01 
{54165} normal block at 0x00FE3B40, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < ; : > 88 3B FE 00 F8 3A FE 00 00 9D A7 01 
{54164} normal block at 0x00FE3AF8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <@; : ` > 40 3B FE 00 B0 3A FE 00 60 AD A7 01 
{54163} normal block at 0x00FE3AB0, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < : ; > F8 3A FE 00 88 3B FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{54162} normal block at 0x00FE2260, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <`: > 60 3A FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{54161} normal block at 0x00FE3A58, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < ! h `" : > D0 21 FE 00 68 F8 03 00 60 22 FE 00 B0 3A FE 00 
{53205} normal block at 0x00FE23B8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <8 @n > 38 F7 03 00 A8 FA 03 00 40 6E A7 01 
{53051} normal block at 0x0003FAA8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < #  > B8 23 FE 00 88 20 FE 00 C0 BA A7 01 
{52897} normal block at 0x00FE2088, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < 8 G > A8 FA 03 00 38 F7 03 00 A8 47 A7 01 
{2104} normal block at 0x00FE2370, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < # > 10 23 FE 00 00 00 00 00 
{2103} normal block at 0x00FE2308, 40 bytes long.
 Data: < p# p l > A8 F9 03 00 A8 F9 03 00 70 23 FE 00 70 00 6C 00 
{1918} normal block at 0x00FE2040, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < 0 > 18 F6 03 00 F8 1F FE 00 30 81 A7 01 
{1878} normal block at 0x00FE1FF8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <@ ( > 40 20 FE 00 10 D8 03 00 28 BA A7 01 
{1874} normal block at 0x0003D810, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <  O > F8 1F FE 00 C8 D7 03 00 20 4F A7 01 
{1810} normal block at 0x0003D7C8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <  m > 10 D8 03 00 80 D7 03 00 F0 6D A7 01 
{1782} normal block at 0x0003D780, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < h 8 > C8 D7 03 00 68 D2 03 00 38 AF A7 01 
{1780} normal block at 0x0003D268, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <  ` > 80 D7 03 00 90 FB 03 00 10 60 A7 01 
{1778} normal block at 0x0003FB90, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <h  > 68 D2 03 00 18 F6 03 00 D8 B9 A7 01 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(188) : {643} normal block at 0x0003D8F0, 62 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 10 00 00 00 16 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\wincore.cpp(4553) : {592} client block at 0x0003C9C0, subtype c0, 56 bytes long.
a CObject object at $0003C9C0, 56 bytes long
{579} normal block at 0x0003F9A8, 40 bytes long.
 Data: < # #  > 08 23 FE 00 08 23 FE 00 CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
{578} normal block at 0x0003F960, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <x > 78 FE 13 00 00 00 00 00 
{577} normal block at 0x0003F908, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < > "  > E8 3E FE 00 A8 22 FE 00 CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
{576} normal block at 0x0003F8C0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <L > 4C FE 13 00 00 00 00 00 
{575} normal block at 0x0003F868, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <X: /  > 58 3A FE 00 B0 2F FE 00 CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
{574} normal block at 0x0003F820, 8 bytes long.
 Data: << > 3C FE 13 00 00 00 00 00 
{573} normal block at 0x0003F7C8, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <  > C8 F7 03 00 C8 F7 03 00 CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
{572} normal block at 0x0003F780, 8 bytes long.
 Data: <, > 2C FE 13 00 00 00 00 00 
{571} normal block at 0x0003F738, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < # > 88 20 FE 00 B8 23 FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{570} normal block at 0x0003F6F0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < > 1C FE 13 00 00 00 00 00 
{569} normal block at 0x0003F6A8, 12 bytes long.
 Data: <  > A8 F6 03 00 A8 F6 03 00 CD CD CD CD 
{568} normal block at 0x0003F660, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < > 0C FE 13 00 00 00 00 00 
{567} normal block at 0x0003F618, 12 bytes long.
 Data: < @ > 90 FB 03 00 40 20 FE 00 CD CD CD CD 
{566} normal block at 0x0003F5D0, 8 bytes long.
 Data: < > F8 FD 13 00 00 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\oleinit.cpp(84) : {563} client block at 0x0003F4C0, subtype c0, 68 bytes long.
a CCmdTarget object at $0003F4C0, 68 bytes long
{439} client block at 0x00038F80, subtype c0, 64 bytes long.
a CDynLinkLibrary object at $00038F80, 64 bytes long
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {433} normal block at 0x00038D60, 28 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 05 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {432} normal block at 0x00038D08, 28 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 05 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {431} normal block at 0x00038C98, 52 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 11 00 00 00 11 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {430} normal block at 0x00037D48, 40 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 0B 00 00 00 0B 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {429} normal block at 0x00037CE8, 32 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 07 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {428} normal block at 0x00037C90, 28 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 05 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {427} normal block at 0x00037C20, 46 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 0E 00 00 00 0E 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {426} normal block at 0x00037BB0, 48 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 0F 00 00 00 0F 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {424} normal block at 0x000387F0, 42 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 0C 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {423} normal block at 0x00038798, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {422} normal block at 0x00038740, 28 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 05 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {421} normal block at 0x000386D0, 50 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 10 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {420} normal block at 0x00038678, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {419} normal block at 0x00038620, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {418} normal block at 0x000385C8, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {417} normal block at 0x00038570, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {416} normal block at 0x00038518, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 03 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {415} normal block at 0x000384C0, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {414} normal block at 0x00038468, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {413} normal block at 0x00038400, 40 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 0B 00 00 00 0B 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {412} normal block at 0x000383A8, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {411} normal block at 0x00038340, 44 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 0D 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {410} normal block at 0x000382D8, 38 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 0A 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {409} normal block at 0x00038280, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {408} normal block at 0x00038228, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {407} normal block at 0x000381C0, 38 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 0A 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {406} normal block at 0x00038168, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {405} normal block at 0x00038110, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 03 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {404} normal block at 0x000380B8, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 03 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {403} normal block at 0x00038058, 36 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {402} normal block at 0x00038000, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 03 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {401} normal block at 0x00037FA8, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {400} normal block at 0x00037F50, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {399} normal block at 0x00037EF8, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {398} normal block at 0x00037EA0, 24 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 03 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {397} normal block at 0x00037E48, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {396} normal block at 0x00037DF0, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {395} normal block at 0x00036D58, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {394} normal block at 0x00036D00, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {393} normal block at 0x00036CA8, 28 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 05 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {391} normal block at 0x00037B38, 60 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 15 00 00 00 15 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {390} normal block at 0x00037AC8, 46 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 0E 00 00 00 0E 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {389} normal block at 0x00037A60, 42 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 0C 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {388} normal block at 0x00037A08, 28 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 05 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {387} normal block at 0x000379A8, 32 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 07 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {386} normal block at 0x00037940, 44 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 0D 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {385} normal block at 0x000378D0, 50 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 10 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {384} normal block at 0x00037858, 60 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 15 00 00 00 15 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {383} normal block at 0x000371A0, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {382} normal block at 0x00037130, 48 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 0F 00 00 00 0F 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {381} normal block at 0x000370D8, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {72} normal block at 0x00036FE0, 32 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 07 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {71} normal block at 0x00036F88, 28 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 05 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {70} normal block at 0x00036F20, 44 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 0D 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {69} normal block at 0x00036EC0, 34 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 08 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {68} normal block at 0x00036E60, 30 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 06 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {67} normal block at 0x000347C0, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {66} normal block at 0x00036DE8, 56 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 13 00 00 00 13 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {65} normal block at 0x00034768, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {63} normal block at 0x00036C38, 48 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 0F 00 00 00 0F 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {62} normal block at 0x00036BE0, 28 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 05 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {61} normal block at 0x00036B88, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {60} normal block at 0x00036B10, 54 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 12 00 00 00 12 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {59} normal block at 0x00036AB0, 34 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 08 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {58} normal block at 0x00036A58, 22 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 02 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\strcore.cpp(156) : {57} normal block at 0x000369F8, 36 bytes long.
 Data: < x  > E4 B8 B3 78 09 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

The reason why i suspect my program has memory leak is that I am building a prototype for my algorithms. The algorithm include intensive computing between xml nodes and using list to add and remove IXMLDOMNode elements in for and while loop. The algorithm is quite linear that supposes I have 288 elements. Initially, each element is itself a list that contains only one element, so a original list contains 288 sub-lists. When the estimated value between any two is large enough, they are merged and put into a new list, and remove from the original list, until the value is small enough or the original list is empty.

The problem is when i ran the program, it hung, if i reduced the size of the data (less xml nodes), it will succeed but require large memory and alot time to process the data. After updating to VS2010 sp1, the problem seems to be alleviated, but still when i run the app, it hangs up for a few seconds, and then back to normal and show results that i expected; but when it involved more intensive computation, more data to be processed, the app just hung, and progressively consumed memory, eat up as much as the system has.

I am running VC10 on 32 bit win xp with sp3, the pc has 3GB RAM usable, although installed 4GB.

Comment: yea, i know, and i am eager to fix them now, but dont know how.

Comment: Looks like these might be leaks in MFC, not in your own code.

Comment: yea, i am coding a MFC dialog-based project.

Comment: You have found out where the MFC source files are stored on the build server in Redmond.  They are in the vc\atlmfc\src\mfc directory on your machine.  No point in looking there, MFC doesn't leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source is from the MFC, but could just be because you have an MFC object that wasn't released, and some of its data was created in the MFC code, and wasn't released because the object itself wasn't released.

I'd check to see if you have any MFC objects that aren't disposed properly.

Comment: what do you mean by "MFC objects", how to check them?

Comment: Well, you probably have some code somewhere (you didn't give us a code sample) that creates an MFC object via an MFC function. That function creates the object within the MFC scope (files), therefor you it shows you those lines. BUT the real reason for the leak is probably that you aren't releasing it like you should. Go to those lines, and trace the MFC function that is called, and then see where You are calling it.

Comment: i updated some info in my original post, and i have reached the char limit in my post. and I also used memory snapshots at the begin and end of some functions, and it shows that there are memory leaks, and so i am really confused if there are memory leaks or not (see the first reply).

Comment: When you exit the program, are you destroying the XMLDom tree ?

Comment: Well, if you're creating an object dynamically.. you should destroy it.

Comment: i use a lot smart pointers including the xml doc, IXMLDOMDocumentPtr, so it should do a self de-reference when exit.

Comment: smart pointers are problematic if you have cyclic connections (objects pointing at one another, or a loop of objects). You could try and check that.

Comment: Just pointing out things you can debug. Can;t help much with no code.

Comment: plz take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485385/code-that-gives-me-possible-memory-leak-problem; i included the code there.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks in the end, add this line to the beginning of the program:

```
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG) | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
```

When _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks is called manually, it makes false leak report, including a lot of static data which is not released yet. If you still have memory leaks, ensure that every source file has DEBUG_NEW redifinition to see allocation source file and line number.

If you are working with MFC, don't call _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks and don't use _CrtSetDbgFlag at all - MFC calls _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks automatically just before exit.

Comment: thx for reply, since my project is MFC dialog-based, so I guess I should put _CrtSetDbgFlag() in OnInitDialog()? also, define  _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC and DEBUG_NEW should have the same effect?

Comment: yea, when i remove _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks and _CrtSetDbgFlag, the output panel of debugger didnt report any memory leaks.

Comment: For testing, add some "real" memory leak and see that it is reported. MFC projects are created with biult-in memory leak tracking, you don't need to add anything. Don't forget to add DEBUG_NEW definition to every new source file added to MFC project.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity

You haven't said what is the HANG (Exception, exit code, anything)?
There could be literally million things you have done wrong.
But let's focus on several problems you have stated clearly.

1. Low on program memory.

   Install 64-bit OS. Your 32-bit process on 32-bit OS is limited to
   2GB memory for working set. When using 64-bit OS, 32-bit process can
   be run with 4GB working set, if you enable /LARGEADDRESSAWARE. This
   way you will have at least twice the current memory working set of
   your application. Or otherwise use x64 (AMD64) for your project
   (mostly all available memory).
2. Large XML.

   How large XML (MB/GB)!? What implementation of XML reader are you using? I've
   found [RapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/) to be very handy. Cause it does all in memory (read XML
   content). And has very small overhead when loading huge XML files, also very
   fast. You may try that one.
3. You have memory leaks.

   When Debugging C++ you can enable debug memory leaks [MSDN: Find memory leaks with the CRT library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library?view=vs-2022). I'll try quickly in few steps to help you set up your code for this.

**How to enable debugging memory leaks in CRT**

a. First you must define and include CRT debug headers
If using precompiled headers open PCH.h (stdafx.h - older versions). Otherwise, if not using precompiled headers, place in your project main header file the following code:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define DBG_NEW new ( _NORMAL_BLOCK , __FILE__ , __LINE__ )
// Replace _NORMAL_BLOCK with _CLIENT_BLOCK if you want the
// allocations to be of _CLIENT_BLOCK type
#else
#define DBG_NEW new
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
// ... other definitions ...
```

b. Must tell Debug CRT to dump memory leaks on program termination.
So on program initialization main entry function (main(), or wininit(), or what ever model you are using main proc.) add the following code:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG) | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
#endif
```

Memory leaks shall be reported in output debug window when project is run and terminated in DEBUG session/configuration as following:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{333} normal block at 0x0051F6C0, 800 bytes long.
 Data: <                > DE 08 07 00 00 00 00 00 86 09 0A 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

NOTE: the above report shall also be reported if you are using MFC in project.
But in case of default or MFC we still do not have the source location of the actual leak.

Now if you want to find source location that leaked, you must replace all code with 'new ...' with 'DBG_NEW ...', if you are unsure that allocation has leaked.

Once you have done the above then the report shall also include the source line where it was leaked similar to the following output:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
x:\work\acdseemods\acdseemods.cpp(36) : {333} normal block at 0x008FF6C0, 800 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 06 09 08 00 00 00 00 00 86 09 0A 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

Preferably this should be run on smaller set of data (XML) so you can quickly fix the code that is leaking memory.
Golden rule, all memory (allocation) you are not using, not need it, free it immediately.

For more details how to do specific things when debugging memory leaks read the MSDN article.

Hope this helps others to fix their memory issues.